# How to remove padding and border from table cells?

Tags: html, css, html-table

I tried a lot of solutions that I have found here and in Google, but no one of them works. 
The table is dynamically generated by jQuery and Javascript.

Question: 
**How can I remove the padding, border between the cells in this html table ?**

This is the HTML code:-

```
<div class="board">
     <table id="tableGame">

     </table>
</div>
```

This is the Css Code

```
.board{
    float:left;
    display: inline-block;
}

table{
    border-collapse: collapse;
}

table tr, td{
    border: 0px;
}
```

Javascript Code below

```
function mapGenerate(){
    var map=createMap(); // this function returns a 2d array filled of random 1 and 0 

/* example 
map = [[1,1,1,1,0],
       [1,0,0,0,0],
       [1,0,1,1,1],
       [1,0,0,0,1],
       [1,1,1,0,1]]
*/    

        //loop the 2d array map and change the number with the appropriate img    
        for(var i = 0; i < map.length; i++) {
            var innerArrayLength = map[i].length;
            for(var j = 0; j<innerArrayLength; j++){
                //loop the nested arrays so i can change the 1 and the 0 with the appropriate img
                if(map[i][j] === 0){
                    map[i][j]="<img class=\"walkble\" src=\"mapTiles/floorResized.png\">"; //you can walk this part of the map
                }else{
                    map[i][j]="<img class=\"nonWalkble\"// you cannot walk This part of the map src=\"mapTiles/volcanoresize.png\">";
                }    
                ;
            }
            $("#tableGame").append("<tr><td>"+ map[i] + "</td></tr>") // Here i print the elements of the array
        }  
    }


mapGenerate();
```

Link to jsfiddle under here.

The problem is not about the 3rd white line ( it only appears in js fiddle, if I open it in my browser they looking as a normal table).

The problem is only to delete that disturbing padding between the cells.

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/legeo/n7gdeu6r/14/)

In codepen you will see it better, without lines error.

[codepen](https://codepen.io/legeo/pen/rrRraz)

Comment: Please provide codeopen or jsbin link with problem. Think in addition to table layout also you should clear some default browsers padding or margins.

Comment: Done it! really thank you for this advice, in the future i will consider to share my code only with jsfiddle or codepen preview :) thanks a lot !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

looks like the problem is on line 80 of your javascript.

`$("#tableGame").append("<tr><td>"+ map[i] + "<td></tr>")`

you're concat-ing an array (`map[i]`) into a string. javascript by default "stringify" it by `join`ing it with commas.

The code above is like:

`$("#tableGame").append("<tr><td>"+ map[i].join() + "<td></tr>")`

since the default joining string is comma, that's equivalent to

`$("#tableGame").append("<tr><td>"+ map[i].join(',') + "<td></tr>")`

To get rid of the commas you simply joining it with an empty string

`$("#tableGame").append("<tr><td>"+ map[i].join('') + "<td></tr>")`

Comment: Man really thank you, i learn a good lesson from your words. Really thank you :)

Answer (score 2):

In HTML, there are attributes `border`, `cellpadding`, and `cellspacing` on the `<table>` element. Set them to 0. `<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">`.

Border is for the border width.

Cellpadding is for the padding in the table cells.

Cellspacing is for the space between the table cells.

Comment: they are obsolete in html5, but thanks the same for the answer :)

Comment: There are CSS equivalents, if you are looking for strict compliance.

Comment: They are not obsolete, they still do the job. And they are actually the standard for email design, as the major email clients still rely on old standards.   
Feel free to go with the css classes, but I would also include it in the table markup, to cover your basis.

Answer (score 0):

css:

```
table { border-collapse: collapse; }
table td { padding:0; }
```

Comment: Table cells do not have margin, just padding.